# Why I am getting OutOfMemory Exception?

Tags: java, android

I am getting OutOfMemory Exception. Why? I am using this code for logging. Does this approach correct?
Exceptions and closing of streams are handled in parent methods.

```
private static void writeToFile(File file, FileWriter out, String message) throws IOException {
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        if ((file.length() + message.getBytes().length) <= FILE_MAX_SIZE_B) {
            out.write(message);
        } else {
            int cutLenght = (int) (file.length() + message.getBytes().length - FILE_MAX_SIZE_B);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
            char[] buf = new char[1024];
            int numRead = 0;
            StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer(1000);
            while ((numRead=bufferedReader.read(buf)) != -1) {
                text.append(buf,0,numRead);
            }
            String result = new String(text).substring(cutLenght);
            result += message;
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, appendToFile);
            writeToFile(file, fileWriter, result);
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I am using this method for writting my logs in file. So for example in one second I can call 10 logs. I am getting error on lines:

```
while ((numRead=bufferedReader.read(buf)) != -1) {
                text.append(buf,0,numRead);
            }
```

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: Please add stack trace to your question.

Comment: I assume you do not care *exactly* about a maximum byte size. Truncating text with surrogate pairs (e.g. UTF-8/UTF-16 etc. etc.) that crosses the maximum length might lead to you having a "crap" character at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting the OutOfMemoryError because you are reading the entire contents of the log file back into memory once it has gotten too close to its maximum size.

You could instead read and write it in smaller chunks, but that could be tricky since you have to avoid overwriting something you haven't already read.

Overall, this technique seems like a very inefficient method of maintaining the log data.  Some alternative approaches off the top of my head:

(1) maintain a set of n log files, each with maximum size FILE_MAX_SIZE_B/n.  When the first log fills up, open the next one for writing, and so on; when the last one fills up, go back to the first one.  In this way you are discarding some of the oldest log data each time you switch files, but not all of it, and still maintaining your overall size limit.

(2) rotate the data within a single file.  After each write, add a marker that indicates this is the end of the log stream.  When the file has reached its maximum size, just start again at the beginning, overwriting the data that is there.  The marker will tell you where the latest message is.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
void appendToFile(File f, CharSequence message, Charset cs, long maximumSize) throws IOException {
    long available =  maximumSize - f.length();
    if (available > 0) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
        try {
            CharBuffer chars = CharBuffer.wrap(message);
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * 1024); // Re-used when encoding the string
            CharsetEncoder enc = cs.newEncoder();
            CoderResult res;
            do {
                res = enc.encode(chars, bytes, true);
                bytes.flip();
                long len = Math.min(available, bytes.remaining());
                available -= len;
                fos.write(bytes.array(), bytes.position(), (int) len);
                bytes.clear();
            } while (res == CoderResult.OVERFLOW && available > 0);
        } finally {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Testable with this:

```
    File f = new File(getCacheDir(), "tmp.txt");
    f.delete();

    // Or whatever charset you want.
    Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    int maxlen = 2 * 1024; // For this test, 2kb
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxlen / 20; i++) {
            // Write 30 characters for maxlen/20 times == guaranteed overflow
            appendToFile(f, "123456789012345678901234567890", cs, maxlen);
            System.out.println("Length=" + f.length());
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    f.delete();
```

Comment: Thanks for code. But would this code  appropriated for situation when I can call this method for example 20 times in a second? I think that my approach  is incorrect .But thanks for reply  - I test this code later.

Comment: Writing repeatedly to file is not optimal, but this will clamp the size of the file to your limit and not use to much memory doing so (you can tweak the conversion buffers size where `bytes` is allocated, 8kb is usually kind of excessive for small string logging, something like 256 is sufficent).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're getting OOM because you're trying to load a huge file into memory.

Did you try [opening it with `append` option](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/AppendToFile.html) instead?

Answer (score 0):

you get OOME because you load the whole file, then get some part of the string. Instead, do a skip on your input stream and read.

Comment: How can I then delete old lines and add new files to log to satisly file max size?